# Reading XML bringing back no results

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml I need to read the values of:

```
<po-response xmlns="http://test.com<" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="rest/oms/export/v3/purchase-order.xsd">
  <!--Generated on Sellpo host [spapp402p.prod.ch4.s.com]-->
  <purchase-order>
    <customer-order-confirmation-number>123456</customer-order-confirmation-number>
    <customer-email>test@test.com</customer-email>
    <po-number>00001</po-number>
    <po-date>2012-02-12</po-date>
    <po-time>06:58:40</po-time>
    <po-number-with-date>12100000000</po-number-with-date>
    <unit>123</unit>
    <site>Test</site>
    <channel>VD</channel>
    <location-id>1234</location-id>
    <expected-ship-date>2012-02-13</expected-ship-date>
    <shipping-detail>
      <ship-to-name>JON DOE</ship-to-name>
      <address>123 SOMETHING STREET</address>
      <city>NEW NEW</city>
      <state>PS</state>
      <zipcode>BG121</zipcode>
      <phone>012030401</phone>
      <shipping-method>Ground</shipping-method>
    </shipping-detail>
  </purchase-order>
</po-response>
```

I'm trying to extract the information from the `shipping-detail` element as follows but nothing is being brought back?

```
                xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());

                var details = from detail in xmlDoc.Descendants("shipping-detail")
                                select new
                                {
                                    Name = detail.Element("ship-to-name").Value,
                                    Address = detail.Element("Address").Value,
                                    City = detail.Element("city").Value,
                                };


                foreach (var detail in details)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ship to Name: " + detail.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Ship to Name: " + detail.Address);
                    Console.WriteLine("Ship to Name: " + detail.City);
                }
```

Comment: You have a namespace, therefore your queries need to use it.

Comment: Is `details` empty, or are the `Name`, `Address`, and `City` properties not populated?

Comment: @Ed S.: How would I include the namespace into the queries then?

Comment: The documentation would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your XML is invalid - assuming your namespace declaration is like this  `xmlns="http://test.com"`, you can get your nodes using the namespace:

```
xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
XNamespace ns = "http://test.com";
var details = from detail in xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "shipping-detail")
                select new
                {
                    Name = detail.Element(ns + "ship-to-name").Value,
                    Address = detail.Element(ns + "address").Value,
                    City = detail.Element(ns + "city").Value,
                };
```

Also keep in mind that node names are case-sensitive, so it's `"address"` and not `"Address"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, yep that works perfectly adding in the namespace as you've suggested...

Answer (score -1):

Your query snippet:

```
xmlDoc.Descendants("shipping-detail")
```

is going to look at the Root node. You don't have any Root nodes named "shipping-detail".

Try

```
xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("shipping-detail")
```

Comment: If the answer is wrong let me know why. I hadn't considered using the namespace as @BrokenGlass recommends. I agree, it would be a far better approach.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but `Descendants()` will match any descendant, no matter how far removed, your example and solution would make sense if `Elements()` was used, which only returns direct children